# clearcase - apply label over multiple labels

Tags: label, clearcase

I need to apply a label on a set of two or more labels that are already created using cleartool. I know how to create and apply a label using cleartool and have studied mklabel command. But couldn't find any provision to apply a label over multiple labels.
Can anyone please provide solution for the same??

Answer (score 1):

You could try and find all the relevant versions (the ones with the right labels) and perform a `mklabel`.

cleartool find can be combined with an exec directive including a mklabel.

```
cleartool find . -ver "lbtype(LBL1) || lbtype(LBL2)" \
   -exec "cleartool mklabel -replace NEW_LBL \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\"
```

The tricks though are:

- you need to list your labels from the oldest to the newest (here `LBL2` must be created more recently than `LBL1`) because **you can `mklabel` only one version per file**: if a file has *two* different versions each labeled with one of your label, you want to end up with your new label on the most recent one. Hence the order in the find query.
- you need the '`-replace`' option of the `mklabel`, because again, if two versions are found, the first `mklabel` will work, the second won't unless the `-replace` instructs it to *move* `NEW_LBL` to the second version.