# IBM Rationale Clearcase label

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I'm new to scripting. I came across this, I have to create a label  for file while checking out I tried command `mklabel` but it did not work for me. I think I'm not using it in right format. I work on Unix environment and version control is Rationale ClearCase.

Before checking I have to create a label .

```
cleartool checkout -c "add a" /vob/sample/DataAnlysis/datasets/request_anlysis.sas7bdat
cleartool checkin -c "add a" /vob/sample/DataAnlysis/datasets/request_anlysis.sas7bdat
```

Comment: The text is a little bit hard to understand. I guess, you miss some punctuation here. Maybe a dot somewhere in the second sentence? Making your question clear helps getting answers quicker ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to checkout/checkin a file in order to use [`cleartool mklabel`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm):

```
cleartool mklabel your_label /path/to/your/File
```

You can see that command use in order to label multiple files in:

- "[clearcase - apply label over multiple labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4508418/6309)"
- "[Cleartool: How to apply label to files which are in my current view only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8500379/6309)"